# Sort Realm Objects Alphabetically in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, realm

i have a PhoneBook that want to Sort Realm Objects ( Contacts )  Alphabetically , i followed some Tutorials , but i have Some Problems that Showed in Picture :

[image]

and my Codes are :

MainVC.swift :

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class MainVC: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var contact_tableview: UITableView!

var contactsWithSections = [[ContactItem]]()

var sectionTitles = [String]()

let realm = try! Realm()

var ContactList: Results<ContactItem> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(ContactItem.self)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes =
        [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "IRANSansWeb-Medium", size: 17)!]
    contact_tableview.delegate = self
    contact_tableview.dataSource = self

    let (arrayContacts, arrayTitles) = collation.partitionObjects(array: ContactList, collationStringSelector: #selector(getter: ContactItem.first_name))

}





func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



    return ContactList.count

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell") as! ContactCell

    let item = ContactList[indexPath.row]

    cell.lblName!.text = item.first_name

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let ContactV = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewContact") as! ContactInfoVC
    navigationController?.pushViewController(ContactV, animated: true)
    ContactV.ContactID = ContactList[indexPath.row]
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    contact_tableview.reloadData()
    // to reload selected cell
}





}



let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()

extension UILocalizedIndexedCollation {
    //func for partition array in sections
    func partitionObjects(array:[AnyObject], collationStringSelector:Selector) -> ([AnyObject], [String]) {
        var unsortedSections = [[AnyObject]]()
        //1. Create a array to hold the data for each section
        for _ in self.sectionTitles {
            unsortedSections.append([]) //appending an empty array
        }
        //2. Put each objects into a section
        for item in array {
            let index:Int = self.section(for: item, collationStringSelector:collationStringSelector)
            unsortedSections[index].append(item)
        }
        //3. sorting the array of each sections
        var sectionTitles = [String]()
        var sections = [AnyObject]()
        for index in 0 ..< unsortedSections.count { if unsortedSections[index].count > 0 {
            sectionTitles.append(self.sectionTitles[index])
            sections.append(self.sortedArray(from: unsortedSections[index], collationStringSelector: collationStringSelector) as AnyObject)
            }
        }
        return (sections, sectionTitles)
    }
}
```

Contact.swift :

```
    import UIKit
import RealmSwift



class ContactItem : Object {

    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var first_name = ""
    dynamic var last_name = ""
    dynamic var work_email = ""
    dynamic var personal_email = ""
    dynamic var contact_picture = ""
    dynamic var mobile_number = ""
    dynamic var home_number = ""
    dynamic var isFavorite = false
    dynamic var Notes = ""

}
```

and how i sort them of Last Contact Added to First ? Like Contact Tab in Phone Application in iPhone ...

Regards <3

Comment: Refer to the documentation on sorting https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#sorting

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i read that , but couldn't realize how i can do this in my project

Comment: well instead of trying to apply collation, get a sorted data set instead of just `return realm.objects(ContactItem.self)`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to sort you realm's query result with asc. For example try this:

```
var ContactList: Results<ContactItem> {
    get {
        return realm.objects(ContactItem.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "your property", ascending: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: what i should replace with Your Property ?

Comment: Excuse me , I'm new in swift

Comment: For example, if you want to sort by name alphabetically, you need to put `.sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)`

Comment: Now How i can sort data in a tableView alphabetically by section ? Like Contact in iPhone's PHONE Application ... ? Its Necessary for me ...

Comment: You can use realm's filter. For Example for section begins with a you need to put `filter("name BEGINSWITH 'a' ")`

Comment: i do not understand that how i can change headers and sections , in filter("name BEGINSWITH 'a' ") , this is just filtered names that begin with a , and what about others character to begin with ? how i can handle and define it to others sections ? what i should return for numberofSections ?

Comment: Can you Give me a Clear Example ?

Comment: `func sectionNames(alphabet: String)->Results<ContactItem>{
  return realm.objects(ContactItem.self).filter("name BEGINSWITH[cd] \(alphabet)").sorted(byKeyPath: "name", ascending: true)

}`

Comment: Where i should use this ? please edit my code and give me that , I'm so confusing .. :(